# How to keep all the spaces in a string while using bulma and VUE

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bulma

I am new to bulma.
I am struggling  how to preserving white space on certain elements, while using bulma.
I have a column from a database  that has mutiple space, but shown HTML only one space.
I try to either use tag `<pre>` around column:

```html
<td><pre>{{mysqlcomumn_hasMultipleSpace}}</pre></td>
```

or  to add custom style in css , it all failed to show original multiple space and only can display one space

```html
<table class="whiteSpace" >
    
    <style lang="scss">
    @import "../node_modules/bulma";
    
    .whiteSpace{
        white-space:pre /* or pre-wrap if you want wrapping to still work. */
    }
    </style>
```

can anyone help me hwo to fix it?
VUE + bulma
thanks!

Comment: sorry ,I got mistake

Comment: <td><pre>{{mysqlcomumn_hasMultipleSpace}}</pre></td>
this can work

Comment: if you have a mistake you can edit your post and fix it, if you found an answer then you can answer your own question and select your answer as the correct answer